# Google Maps Static API is asking for API Key

Tags: google-maps

When using the google maps static API service, all my requests are showing up as a 403 Forbidden. When taking a look at my request, I notice this error message: "The Google Maps API server rejected your request. This service requires an API key."

The code that is calling the service is below:

```
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Albany,+NY&zoom=13&scale=false&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&format=png&visual_refresh=true" alt="Google Map of Albany, NY">
```

I've used the static map service before and it worked fine and easily. But for some reason, all my requests show up as a 403 now? I've never had to use an API key in the past. If I do use an API key with this call, it works.

What is going on here?

Comment: You require a key now for this service: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/

Comment: You can supply it your API Key to get up to 25,000 free requests and if you wish to pay for additional quota, then you can sign your URLs to enable billing. If you're using Python you can take a look at https://github.com/allrod5/staticmaps-signature and https://github.com/ryancox/motionless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google Static Maps API now requires a key (as of June 22, 2016), existing applications should be "grandfathered" with keyless access.  See [this blog post](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.es/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html) for more information (relevant text below):

> As of June 22, 2016 we are making the following changes to the Google Maps APIs Standard Plan:
>
> 1. We no longer support keyless access (any request that doesn't include an API key). Future product updates are only available for requests made with an API key. API keys allow us to contact developers when required and help us identify misbehaving implementations.
> 2. We have implemented a simple 25,000 map loads per day free limit to new Google Maps JavaScript API, Static Maps API, and Street View Image API implementations. The confusing 90-consecutive-day grace period for these APIs is being retired on October 12, 2016. With this change, developers can predictably plan for growth while media sites and US nonprofits can request more quota at no charge via our dedicated support programs.
> 3. We have reduced the daily map load maximum limit you can purchase for Google Maps JavaScript API, Static Maps API, and Street View Image API from 1,000,000 to 100,000 requests per API.* We believe higher-volume developers are best served with a Premium Plan license, which includes technical support and a Service Level Agreement, and with this change we've also created consistency between Standard Plan quotas across our maps and web service APIs.
> 4. We now count Google Maps JavaScript API client-side requests towards the daily limit of the associated web service API.*
>
> The new policies will apply immediately to all Maps API implementations created on or after June 22nd, 2016.
>
> Existing applications have been grandfathered based on their current usage to ensure that they continue to function both now and in the future. We will also be proactively contacting all existing API key users who, based on usage growth patterns, may be impacted in the future. If you’re an existing user, please take the time to read our Policy Update for Standard Plan summary for details on how each of these changes might affect your implementation.